# Python. How to solve "setuptools must be installed to install from a source distribution"

Tags: pip, gitlab, setuptools

I have a Continuous Integration that works with Gitlab. When I deploy, it installs everything in my requirements.txt file with pip. However, when it gets to installing a package named cffi, it throws the error:

> Downloading/unpacking cffi==1.10.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line
>   11)) Cleaning up...
>
> setuptools must be installed to install from a
>   source distribution

I am lost here. Tried adding "setuptools" to requirements.txt and adding a line that explicitly installs it, but it doesn't work.

`gitlab.ci` looks like this:

```
script:
        - "cp tests/test_settings.py app/local_settings.py"
        - "source /home/ci/misuper-venv/bin/activate"
        - pip install setuptools
        - "pip install -r requirements.txt"
        - "python manage.py migrate --noinput"
```

I'm completely lost here. Please help.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It's a known problem.

```
pip install -U setuptools
pip install -U pip
```

Just helped me.

*Note:* a reasonable person would *never* `sudo pip install` anything.
OS's Python should be managed by the OS's package manager; strong-arming your *system* Python installation has been many times seen to break your OS in interesting ways.

To `pip install` *anything*, use `virtualenv` or an equivalent.

Comment: using sudo on the both the above commands solved my issues thank you

Comment: @jamesc: Good! But next time consider using a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). System Python packages are best handled by your package manager.

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue when trying to install Pillow. After running the above it installed with no problems.